# Javascript / JQuery - Favor Number Range In Math.random()

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

---

**Description:**
I have created a small project that generates random navbar designs. Part of the randomality is the `border-radius` of the navbar can range from `0` to `100`. But once you start going over 5 pixels on the border radius you can really start to see the curvature of the border. 5 out of 100 is very small so 95% of the time there will be a very noticeable curve on the navbar that randomly generates. How can I tone down the 95% without changing the range of `0` to `100`? So the navbar has a larger chance to generate with a sharp edge.

---

**Code:**

```
var borderRadius = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 0;
```

Comment: Thank you, I will read over it and if it is a duplicate I will certainly accept the duplicate as the answer to this question.

Comment: Check the answer by Thomas Eding... it's simple and fits right in with your use case.